# XAML custom text in TextBlock

Tags: wpf, xaml

Good afternoon,

I´m binding a list of doubles (`Latlng`) to an `ItemsControl` and in a `TextBlock` I want to make a custom text when the list binded has a count of 0. With the code I have the `TextBlock` is empty when the `ItemsSource` of the `ItemsControl` is that list.

What am I doing wrong?

Btw the list `Latlng` is a property of a class.

```xml
<ItemsControl Name="icLatLng" ItemsSource="{Binding Latlng}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14">
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style>
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Text" Value="{Binding}"></Setter>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}, Path=Items.Count}" Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.Text" Value="—"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

`ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` is the template that gets applied to each element in the Items list the control is bound to. If there are no items to begin with, then it won't be created, so anything you do in it won't be seen.

I suspect what you're really trying to do is replace the look of the entire control when the list is empty. If so, you can do that by applying a new template to the ItemsControl itself using a DataTrigger on the `HasItems` property:

```
<ItemsControl Name="icLatLng" ItemsSource="{Binding Latlng}">
    <ItemsControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ItemsControl}}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
                                <TextBlock Text="-" />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.Style>
</ItemsControl>
```